# Have I to define custom exception class ItemValidAccess in mehod?

Tags: laravel, laravel-exceptions

On laravel 10 site I made a method which returns true or ItemValidAccess exception in case of invalid data :

```
   /**
     * Determine whether logged user have access to complete item
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Item  $item
     *
     * @return true | ItemValidAccess -
     */
    public static function onlyOwnerCanCompleteItem(Item $item): true | ItemValidAccess {
        throw_if(
            $item->creator_id !== Auth::user()->id,
            ItemValidAccess::class,
            __('You are not allowed to complete this item')
        );

        return true;
    }
```

Is it correct way to define ItemValidAccess in method description as there is no return statement when I run throw_if ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you only validate, it makes no sense to return `true` and nothing else. In those cases just do the validation and if it fails, throw the exception and done, because if it does not fail, of course you would get `true` back (adds no value at all), so your code should be like:

```
/**
 * Determine whether logged user have access to complete item
 *
 * @throws ItemValidAccess
 */
public static function onlyOwnerCanCompleteItem(Item $item): void {
    throw_if(
        $item->creator_id !== Auth::user()->id,
        ItemValidAccess::class,
        __('You are not allowed to complete this item')
    );
}
```

There is also one more "issue", if you throw an exception, it is an stardard to have `Exception` in the name: `ItemInvalidAccessException` makes more sense.